# Reference 'column_name' is ambiguous

Tags: java, apache-spark, spring-boot, apache-spark-sql

I am trying the following join query on java spark dataset:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from ScheduledTaskTable AS ST1 "
+ "FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * from OpenTaskTable WHERE due_date = cast('"+unscheduledDate+"' as timestamp) " 
+ "AND csg_order_id NOT IN(SELECT ST2.csg_order_id from  ScheduledTaskTable AS ST2)) AS UnscheduledTaskTable "
+ "ON ST1.csg_order_id = UnscheduledTaskTable.csg_order_id");
```

The ScheduledTaskTable is derived from OpenTaskTable. I am trying an outer join between ScheduledTaskTable and records from OpenTaskTable which has due_date = 'certain value' and not present in ScheduledTaskTable. 
But when I am trying to run the above query, spark is giving following error:

```
 Reference 'ST2.csg_order_id' is ambiguous, could be: csg_order_id#1, csg_order_id#71.; line 1 pos 165
```

I searched about the problem, but could not find any strong solution for spark sql. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks to me like a bug in spark.  I think you should try contacting Apache, using whatever mechanism they specify on the spark website.

Comment: It looks like you have two columns with the same name in the `ScheduledTaskTable` table, are you sure that is not the case?

Comment: @Shaido it is not possible. If that would be the case, I won't be able to create ScheduleTaskTable at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

When you have duplicate columns you should use the following approach:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("csg_order_id"), "full_outer")
```

Not sure how to do that only with SQL. Maybe adding table aliases and using them when selecting columns.

Comment: Seq() is used in scala

Answer (score 0):

Got it. As I said, the ScheduledTaskTable is derived from OpenTaskTable; so I added an alias while retrieving ScheduledTaskTable, like this:
Previously I was writing query to derive scheduleTaskTable like this:

```
Select * from OpenTaskTable WHERE (some condition);
```

instead add an alias like:

```
Select OT.* from OpenTaskTable AS OT WHERE (Some condition);
```

This way spark is able to recognize attributes for both datasets (OpenTaskTable and ScheduledTaskTable) separately.
The crux is, if you are creating a spark query to fetch data, its best to use alias, so that later if you want to join the dataset with some other dataset which has same column name(s), the spark will be able to recognize the columns by looking up their alias names.